# Microsoft Fabric, connect data pipeline to onpremise source

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I am working with microsoft fabric and I need to create a data pipeline to extract information from a folder located on an onpremise server, but I don't see any connector from fabric that allows me to connect to this source onpremise, how can I do this?

Comment: Question: what is your on-prem data, is it SQL or csv/ any other file format?

Comment: You'll need some sort of Self Hosted Integration Runtime and normal Azure Data Factory pipeline to get your data from On Prem to the fabric storage account. Or use AZCopy to move data from your on prem to the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

On-prem data gateway support for Fabric is on Q1 2024 roadmap. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/release-plan/data-factory#opdg

Pending that awesome feature, I've pushing files to Fabric from PowerAutomate using HTTP w Azure AD connector.
PAuto does whatever through the gateway, sends a file to a Fabric folder, a high-frequency pipeline job picks it up, and hands it off to a notebook/script/dataflow - whatever works for your use-case.